# Msys2 and Mingw64 system include directory is incorrect preventing the use of GLib

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, glib, msys2

I am doing C development on windows and installed Msys2. With Msys2 `pacman` I installed 64 bit mingw and Glib. I can use the gcc that was installed to compile. The Glib headers is now at `C:\msys64\mingw64\include\glib-2.0` and `C:\msys64\usr\include\glib-2.0`.

When adding `#include <gmodule.h>` to a source file and compiling I get:
`fatal error: gmodule.h: No such file or directory`

Checking the include paths with `gcc -xc -E -v -` I see errors:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-8.2.0/configure --prefix=/mingw64 --with-local-prefix=/mingw64/local --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 -
-host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --with-native-system-header-dir=/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include
--libexecdir=/mingw64/lib --enable-bootstrap --with-arch=x86-64 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=ada,c,lto,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran --enable-shared --enable-static --enable-libatomic --enable-threads=posix --enable-graphite --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts=yes --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --disable-isl-version-check --enable-lto --enable-libgomp --disable-multilib --enable-checking=release --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/mingw64 --with-mpfr=/mingw64 --with-mpc=/mingw64 --with-isl=/mingw64 --with-pkgversion='Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project' --with-bugurl=https://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2 --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.2.0 (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-E' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.2.0/cc1.exe -E -quiet -v -iprefix C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.2.0/ -D_REENTRANT - -mtune=generic -march=x86-64
ignoring duplicate directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.2.0/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "F:/msys64/mingw64/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/mingw64/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.2.0/include-fixed"
ignoring duplicate directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "F:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.2.0/include
 C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../include
 C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.2.0/include-fixed
 C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include
End of search list.
```

How do I fix include paths so that gcc can find the GLib headers? I could add it to a spec file or `C_INCLUDE_PATH` but I it bypasses the error instead of fixing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install `pkg-config`, you can use it to obtain the build flags for glib, like this:

```
$ pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0
-I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include
$ pkg-config --libs glib-2.0       
$ -lglib-2.0
```

The flags will vary from system to system, but the library name (`glib-2.0`) is hopefully consistent.